# Отправка данных конкретному пользователю

Tags: c#, wcf, чат

Использую WCF сервис для создания чата,для идентификации пользователя используются сессии. Когда нужно отправить сообщение я выбираю из базы номер сессии пользователя,которому нужно отправить сообщение,а вот что делать дальше я не понимаю.Как можно отправить конкретному пользователю сообщение по айдишнику ?

Comment: Я это представляю примерно так :
На клиенте делается проверка ID,и если она совпадает,то клиенту выводиться это сообщение.Но мне кажется лучше чтобы сервер сам отправлял сообщение нужному клиенту

Comment: У WCF есть дуплексная модель взаимодействия с клиентом. С помощью этой модели сервер может отсылать сообщения клиенту, вот ссылка на доку https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx